# How to check one condition in two scenarios when app enters in foreground in swift

Tags: swift, camera, uiimageview, foregroundnotification

I have two image upload buttons

1st in profile pic upload button i am using `UIImagePickerController`
2nd in file and image upload button i am using `HSAttachmentPicker` library

**code**: when i open camera and and dismiss and comeback to app then i dont want to call `applicationWillEnterForeground > guard let user = getGeneralInfo?.result?.user else { return }`.

so i used `isCameraMode` variable to check when i open camera but in my second condition image and file upload button using `HSAttachmentPicker` here i couldn't check when i open camera because i have used library so in this condition when i open camera and comeback to app then my `applicationWillEnterForeground` hits and my "getGeneralInfoService()" also refreshes, how to handle this. please do guide me

```
var isCameraMode = false

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)

if !isCameraMode {
    getGeneralInfoService()
}
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  
    if !isCameraMode {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)),
            name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
            object: nil)
    }
    isCameraMode = false
}

@objc func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    if !isCameraMode {
        
        guard let user = getGeneralInfo?.result?.user else { return }
        if user.identity_verification_status == "V"{
            tabIndex = 2
            paymentTextLabel.text = "Your ID has been verified"
        }
    }
}

func openCamera() {
if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera) {
    self.isCameraMode = true
    imagePickerEdit.delegate = self
    imagePickerEdit.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
    imagePickerEdit.allowsEditing = false
    self.present(imagePickerEdit, animated: true, completion: nil)
} 
//works fine
@IBAction func profilePicBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    chooser = .profile
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        self.openCamera()
    }))
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        self.openGallery()
    }))
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


//issue: this is file and image upload button here when i open camera "applicationWillEnterForeground" hits and service call calls
@IBAction func insuranceBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.showAttachmentMenu()
}


}
```

Comment: you are not providing full class. please post full code snippet of every function that are calling from view will appear did load and did appear

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadII, added my `viewDidAppear` code this is the full code, i don't have any other code, please take a look

Comment: getGeneralInfoService()
        getServiceDetail()
        subCategoryServicecall(), inside view will appear what is that

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadII those are all my service calls.. where we can upload image and showing saved image... and `BTW my issue is when i click image with camera then scroll view scrolls to top`

Comment: So does your question boil down to wondering why your view controller's `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` are called after dismissing the camera view? Why wouldn't they be called? The camera covers your view controller. After dismissing the camera, your view controller appears again so those methods get called. Perfectly normal.

Comment: @HangarRash, yes you are correct but my get services are inside `if !isCameraMode {` so they shouldn't call right? but they are calling and my whole screen refreshes with old data. that's my issue

Comment: You set `isCameraMode` in several places. Use the debugger and step through the code. Determine where `isCameraMode` is either not be setting like your thought or being reset unexpectedly. Also keep in mind that `viewDidAppear` will always be called after `viewWillAppear`. So if you reset `isCameraMode` in `viewWillAppear` then it will never be true in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: @HangarRash, please guide me here edited my question

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadII, could you guide me here i have edited my post with what exactly i need

Comment: move all of your code from view will appear and view did appear to view didload and if they are not working as expected than put them in DispatchQueue.main.async if any ui not updated or purple warning

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadII, are you sure `applicationWillEnterForeground` will work in didload?

Comment: app did become active notification use